# The values obtained using X are within ...-...% of those obtained in Y

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

I want to calculate the value percentage in the following scenario:

I have some values obtained using X method and some others obtained using Y method.

The values obtained from X are: 2.5, 1.14, 21.96, 4.66, 1.91, 735.93, 30.96

The values obtained from Y are: 2.5, 1.11, 21.19, 4.63, 1.89, 710.24, 31.02

The values obtained using X are within ...-...% of those obtained in Y.

How do I calculate the percentage on the above statement?

Comment: Please avoid "do my homework for me"-style questions. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or explaining what you tried would be a big step forward! (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Comment: This is not homework, but I get your point. I was compering the results obtained from two different methods, and I was asked to express them using the statement above but I am not sure I understand the statement. I added the values for reference, no need to give me a numeric result. An explanation of the statement would be much more appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would decide on one of $X,Y$ as the standard to measure from and measure the error of the other from that.  If you choose $X$ as the standard for the $i^{th}$ value the error in the calculation of $Y_i$ is $\left|\frac{Y_i-X_i}{X_i}\right|$.  You would calculate all of these and report the maximum or maybe round it up to a nice value.  If the errors are small it won't matter much whether you use $X_i$ or $Y_i$ in the denominator.  If they are large it will matter and you should make it precise.

Comment: By using the formula you described and having X as the standard I obtained the following values: 0, 0.026, 0.035, 0.006, 0.01, 0.034, 0.001.

So, to answer the statement it would be "The values obtained using X are within 0-3.5% of those obtained in Y". Does this make sense or X and Y should be reversed?

Comment: Since $X$ is the standard, you would say the $Y$ values are within $3.5\%$ of the $X$ values.  That indicates you used $X$ in the denominator.  The usual reason to say this is if the $X$ values are hard to calculate and the $Y$ values are easy.  You would be claiming that $3.5\%$ error is close enough for the purpose at hand.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I get it now.